# Enumerating programs in the notification area

Tags: delphi, system, tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the tooltips of notification-area icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203955/how-can-i-get-the-tooltips-of-notification-area-icons)

Done a lot of searching but drawing a blank here.

I can make a list of all the apps running in the task bar and all of the apps and services running in total, but I cannot seem to identify just the apps in the notification area.

I need to find just the application Name or the Caption.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203955/enumerate-systray-icons and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971789/windows-system-tray-icons-controlling-position

Comment: There's no API for this. Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Note that this is not an exact duplicate of the mentioned question. The other question really just wanted to get the tooltips. Supposedly, the person already knew how to enumerate the icons and wasn't asking for that information.

Comment: I have already figured out how to enumerate the icons, (tooltips) but I want the names of the underlying apps for the icons. Thanks so far guys.

Comment: Once again we get a question about notification icons where the person already knows how to enumerate the icons and wants additional information, but the question doesn't say that. @User, tell us what you have so far, and then we can help you get what else you need.